# How can I change CSS class name dynamically with reagent?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

About [reagent](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent).

I need to change some CSS class name dynamically. 
How should I do that?

Sample code is here.

```
(defn app []
  (let [array [1, 2, 3]]
    (fn []
      [:div
       (for [index array]
         ;; I wanna change this classname like `item-1, item-2, ...`
         ^{:key index} [:div.i-wanna-change-this-classname-dynamically index])])))
```

Answer (score 11):

Change

```
[:div.i-wanna-change-this-classname-dynamically index]
```

to

```
[:div {:class (str “item-” index)} index]
```

Reagent provides a shorthand syntax of `:div.class1.class2#id`, but you can also set these in a map as the first item in the vector after `:div`.

Also keep in mind the CSS `:nth-child()` selector as another option for dynamic styling.